# Add one element after first paragraph

Tags: php, wordpress

I've the following code for adding advertisement before `the_content` of posts in my WordPress website.

```
<?php if (!empty($smof_data['ads_entry_top'])) { ?>
   <div class="entry-img-300"><?php echo stripslashes($smof_data['ads_entry_top']); ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

I want it to be added after the first paragraph, so wrote this function into `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'insert_after_first', 20 );

function insert_after_first( $content ) {

    $content = preg_replace( "/<\/p>/", "</p>" . stripslashes($smof_data['ads_entry_top']) , $content, 1 );
    return $content;
}
```

But it does nothing. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I changed my method and now add some content after first paragraph with below function and filter. I add it here maybe it helps someone:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'ata_the_content_filter', 10, 1);
function ata_the_content_filter($content)
{
    $parags = explode('</p>', $content);
    $parags[0] .= '<br>hello';// add whatever you want after first paragraph

    $content_new = '';

    foreach ($parags as $parag) {
        $content_new .= $parag;
    }

    return $content_new;
}
```